# UIScrollView not showing up in the view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am implementing a `UIScrollView` in a `CollectionViewCell`. I have a custom view which the scroll view should display, hence I am performing the following program in the `CollectionViewCell`. I have created everything programmatically and below is my code :

```
struct ShotsCollections {
    let title: String?
}

class ShotsMainView: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()

        containerScrollView.contentSize.width = frame.width * CGFloat(shotsData.count)

        shotsData = [ShotsCollections.init(title: "squad"), ShotsCollections.init(title: "genral")]
        var i = 0
        for data in shotsData {

            let customview = ShotsMediaView(frame: CGRect(x: containerScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: containerScrollView.frame.width, height: containerScrollView.frame.height))

            containerScrollView.addSubview(customview)
            i += 1
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var shotsData = [ShotsCollections]()

    var containerScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let instance = UIScrollView()
        instance.isScrollEnabled = true
        instance.bounces = true
        instance.backgroundColor = blueColor
        return instance
    }()


    private func setupViews() { //These are constraints by using TinyConstraints
        addSubview(containerScrollView)
        containerScrollView.topToSuperview()
        containerScrollView.bottomToSuperview()
        containerScrollView.rightToSuperview()
        containerScrollView.leftToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, while the scrollview is displayed, the content in it is not. I on printing the `contentSize` and `frame` of the scrollview, it displays 0. But if I check the Debug View Hierarchy, scrollview containes 2 views with specific frames.

I am not sure whats going wrongs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your question is answered, you must close the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: @kerry Hey Buddy tried your solution but as I mentioned, having constraints didnt quite convince me and didnt workout aswell. The main thing was to set the frame of the scrollview equal to supreview and assigning the array data above the content size. This itself will create the content scrollable. But I'll definitely upvote for all the prompt help you gave me. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding `customView` in your `containerScrollView`, you are not setting up the constraints between `customView` and `containerScrollView`.

Add those constraints and you will be able to see your `customView`s given that your `customView` has some height. Also, when you add more view, you would need to remove the bottom constraint of the last added view and create a bottom constraint to the `containerScrollView` with the latest added view.

Comment: Well, I dont quite understand adding constraints. I am already providing the frame, to the scrollview. In fact if I perform the same code with a scrollview on a storyboard and rest all programmed it works completely fine. As soon I shift to the programming the scrollview, everything goes south.

Comment: Try to understand the answer. If you are creating everything programmatically, you need to add constraints too programmatically. `NSLayoutConstraints.activate()`. Since you are not adding constraints in customView when you are adding it, you are not able to see it and its height is not getting translated to scrollView height

Comment: Damnit! I see what you are saying, totally get you now. My bad *_facepalms_*.. So well, if I am scrolling horizontally, I should be replacing left and right constraints, right?

Comment: Yes. If you are adding new view on the right then you need replace right constraint of the last view and create a chain with the new view. Then add right constraint of the new view to the right of superview, thus ending the chain.

Comment: So in this case I need to have my views uniquely identified? Can you help me a bit with chaining?

Comment: Checkout horizontal stackview provided by iOS. That will help you with chaining.

Comment: Well, I am aware of that. I am not able to get my head around it for the moment. Are you suggesting adding them to a stack view altogether? Just trying to understand your point clearly

Comment: Yes. Add a stack view in the scroll view. Then add your custom views inside the stack view. The stackview will start growing and so will your scroll view

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample app for your use case. I am pasting the code and the resultant screen shot below. Hope this is the functionality you are looking for. I suggest you paste this in a new project and tweak the code until you are satisfied. I have added comments to make it clear.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Initialize dummy data array with numbers 0 to 9
    var data: [Int] = Array(0..<10)

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        // Add collection view programmatically
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(ShotsMainView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ShotsMainView.identifier)
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor),
            self.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor),
            self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.leadingAnchor),
            self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
 }   

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ShotsMainView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ShotsMainView
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // The cell dimensions are set from here
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100.0)
    }
}
```

**ShotsMainView**
This is the collection view cell

```
import UIKit

class ShotsMainView: UICollectionViewCell {

    static var identifier = "Cell"
    weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // Initialize with zero frame
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Add the scrollview and the corresponding constraints
        let containerScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        containerScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        containerScrollView.bounces = true
        containerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        containerScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(containerScrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerScrollView.topAnchor),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerScrollView.bottomAnchor),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerScrollView.trailingAnchor)
        ])

        // Add the stack view that will hold the individual items that
        // in each row that need to be scrolled horrizontally
        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        containerScrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor),
            containerScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor),
            containerScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor),
            containerScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        // Add individual items (Labels in this case).
        for i in 0..<10 {
            let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            label.text = "\(i)"
            label.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 20.0)
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
            label.layer.masksToBounds = false
            label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            label.textAlignment = .center


            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
                label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0.0)
            ])
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Scrollable rows using UIStackView inside UICollectionViewCell]

Comment: Thank for the reply man. I have put up a detailed question here. Can you take a look?

Comment: I checked your code, I think you are not setting up the constraints properly.You have added constraints for the container scroll view, but I do not see you setting containerScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, which will not get you what you are looking for. You are also not using a stackview and the frames for the views added in the for loop are set explicitly instead of using constraints. I request you to set up a sample project using the code above, understand what's going on and progressively edit the code to match your scenario.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks alot for this. I actually resolved this just with a scrollview. I was actually pointing at this question. can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339775/implement-twitter-profile-like-view-with-parallax-scroll

Comment: Hey man, can you help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656783/dispatch-groups-not-working-on-firebase-database