# Implement twitter Profile like view with parallax scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, parallax

I want to implement the following sort of view where the view can be completely scrolled and houses 2 different scrollview (Main and the secondary) with infinite scrollable content. This represents the exact thing I want.

[image]

1. The **red**  view is superview - should scroll vertically
2. The **green** view is of the height of the current view and is just static. That doesnt scroll
3. The **blue** view is the horizontal scrollview where for each label there is a **yellow** vertically scrolling infinity collection view
4. the labels scroll as in the given video. under each label there is the collection view I mentioned in point 3

The blue box is the scroll view and I want the scrolling to happen horizontally in a parallax way such as this.

[image]

I am able to implement the above parallax in the correct fashion but each title contains their own `collectionview`. When I implement this I am not able to have an infinite scroll. Below is the code for that :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == containerScrollView {
        for i in 0..<shotsData.count {
            let label = scrollView.viewWithTag(i + tagValueL) as! UILabel
            let view = scrollView.viewWithTag(i + tagValueV) as! ShotsMediaView
            let scrollContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.width
            let viewOffset = (view.center.x - scrollView.bounds.width/4) - scrollContentOffset
            label.center.x = scrollContentOffset - ((scrollView.bounds.width/4 - viewOffset)/2)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I exactly achieve the same behavior with an infinite scroll **vertically**? I want each of these titles to have collectionview that have the dynamic height each.

Comment: Do you want both the upper and lower views to scroll left-right so they both have the same behavior? What is the relationship between the upper and lower views, if any?

Comment: I updated the question. The upper view is just an image. the lower view is like a group of cell that just as in representation of the twitter screenshot. The topview is just static but the lower views have feed like content. And there are 2 tabs

Comment: The issue is I have been able to implement a view where the top view is a `CollectionViewHeader(ReusableView)`. and then the scrollview in the gif is in a cell. But I am not able to give it an infinite height. Now I am looking to implement a different architecture as in the diagram

Comment: @jay Anything on it yet?

Comment: I've never worked with side scrolling so I don't have any suggestions yet. I will see if I can take a look in the morning if there isn't a solution although I am sure others have way more experience.

Comment: @Jay appreciate it. Thanks mate

Comment: I understand that when you scroll the content of the yellow box(horizontally), you need to scroll the view with the titles so that the title that matches the content is scrolled to visibility and is highlighted.. am I correct ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim thats perfectly, Yup so the blue box move as shown in the gif. And everything in the yellow box is collectionview vertical infinity scroll. Am I being clear to you?

Comment: yeah.. let me look at this

Comment: Awesome. I want the same functionality as twitter. Just the segmented scroll has to be parallaxed. Also, do suggest if a bettter design if this feels bad.

Comment: @humblePilgrim Hey mate, Did you find anything on it?

Comment: No man, I am a bit busy at the moment :( didn't get time

Comment: was actually waiting for your answer. Thanks man. Once I find a way. I'll share it with you.

Answer (score 2):

I did a crude implementation of this.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == colorsCollectionView {
        let newContentOffSetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let distance = contentOffSetX + newContentOffSetX
        // Scroll the text collection view proportinately
        let titleScrollDistance = (distance/colorsCollectionView.frame.width * 75.0)
        titlesCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: titleScrollDistance, y: titlesCollectionView.contentOffset.y)
        contentOffSetX = newContentOffSetX
    }
}
```

contentOffSetX is a property of the class(ViewController) that I use to keep track of the scrolling distance of the bottom collection view. Initially that is set to 0. When the user scrolls the collection view at the bottom, the above delegate method is called. Then I use the contentOffSet to get the distance that was scrolled along the X-axis. I map that to the width of the title labels(hardcoded as 75.0) to calculate the distance that collection has to be scrolled. Hope this can be refined to serve your purpose, but I am sure that there are better methods out there :)

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with my code, of how I got the gif to work

Comment: Thank a ton for this answer @humblePilgrim, I have literally been waiting for a reply. I have a question though, I want these colored to be UIViews scrolling vertically(Collection view) and the size of each is dynamic. I am not sure how can I achieve this? Can you please help me out here. I was able to achieve this result previously. My issue majorly is deciding the height of each scroll. Am I being clear about my question

Comment: The vertical scrolling is implemented in the above using a table view. The dynamic height of each row can be achieved using autolayout. See this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells